# How to add select field in form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can you please tell me how to add select field in angular js.I am using this field.
https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms
I am able to to add text field and but there is no documentation how I will add select field

http://plnkr.co/edit/zCF4oZ5pNWbARaONSGtY?p=preview

```
var apep=angular.module('app', ['dynform']);
apep.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

       $scope.formTemplate = {
        "first": {
            "type": "text",
            "label": "First Name"
        },
        "last": {
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Last Name"
        },
        "submit": {
            "type": "submit"
        }
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have completed dropdown:

```
"select": {
      "type": "select",
      "label": "Dropdown",
      "options": {
              "1": {
                  "label": "North East"
              },
              "2": {
                  "label": "All"
              },
              "3": {
                  "label": "South Texas"
              },
              "4": {
                  "label": "Permian"
              },
              "5": {
                  "label": "Mid Continent"
              },
              "15": {
                  "label": "West"
              }
          }
    }
```

Plunker here: [Dropdown Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fTjYlLzs1IPtS8Ig8h8e?p=preview)

Comment: i need some option in station..with different display and values..having option in select with different display string having different values

Comment: please share with plunker

Comment: @user3703527 Yes, I am researching

Comment: please remove your anwser so that other will anser

Comment: @user3703527 Already did. Edited answer. My internet is slow today.. Hope it helped! :)

Comment: thanks for help ..sorry for that,..But there is two issue in your anser..you can't slecct any value.and secondly I need different value with different text.example "North East" is display name and I need it value should be "abc"

Comment: @user3703527 let me check

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/KCB4v8DID2T2KYS6rymD?p=preview check this.there is another issue is that some display small white box front of drop down what is dis

Comment: @user3703527 the small box is the empty button.

Comment: hmm..But first two issues so difficult I am doing  RND